# How to pass special characters dynamically in maskRe attribute of Extjs?

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs

As of now, I am trying to achieve success with static values, for eg.,

```
maskRe: /^[A-Za-z0-9 $%]+$/
```

but I wanted to pass **$%** dynamically with some variable instead of hardcoding.

Comment: How is it related to regex ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) class to create a `RegExp` object from a string. The string can be as static as a formatted.

```js
let dynamicValue = "$%";
let regex = new RegExp(`^[A-Za-z0-9 ${dynamicValue}]+$`);

console.log(regex);
```

Comment: It's working in javascript with ExtJS 5.1.0. But when I verify with the same on javascript with ExtJS code 4.1.0 it's not working. Is an alternative way to access it.

Comment: Exactly what does not work?

Comment: I tried with below ways
1)maskRe: new RegExp(`^[A-Za-z0-9 ${dynamicValue}]+$`), // the dynamicValue is empty
2) var dValue=new RegExp(`^[A-Za-z0-9 ${dynamicValue}]+$`);
maskRe:  dValue, //the dValue is empty

Comment: You should declare those values before using them. Note that ````${dynamicValue}```` means: **replace with variable value**. So you should declare `dynamicValue` variable, then execute ```new RegExp(`^[A-Za-z0-9 ${dynamicValue}]+$`);```

Comment: yes in fact I did this. Still the value is empty.

Comment: Then it should probably be an etxjs issue for concrete version.